# I have functional prototype at hand. Should I wait for patent application be finalized?

Tags: application

I have applied for nonprovisional us patent for my product. I want to contact with investors to show them a working product. Is it possible that after my patent application is rejected and investors patent application for the same product is accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone stole your idea and filed it, your rejected application, assuming it was published, would be easy to find prior art that the bad guys would not be able to get around. If they made a patentable change to your invention and were only claiming that new part, they would be legit.

Answer (score 0):

If you filed the patent before the investors did and you comply all the necessary documents regarding your patent. It would be hard for them to get a patent grant for the similar products because of the first-to-file basis. But as what George said, if ever your patent is rejected and prior art is a good defense to prevent other from filing a patent over your invention.